# merge multiple rows in panadas for all columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a data frame with 1000 rows and 100 columns. The first column is the names and the rest are values or empty. Many rows have the same name. How can I add them and have each name once with the summation of the values?

For example the name Alex on the first row has the values 20, 30, 40 and on 2 other rows again we have Alex with values 10,10,20 respectively. So my new data frame should only have the row Alex just once with values  40, 50, 80

EDIT : First of all thank you all for your feedback. Sorry if I was not clear. Imagine I have the following matrix

```
Names        Last name    price1     price2    price3   (no named column)  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alex         Robinson     10         20         30      (a string)
Bill         Towns        10         40         50      (empty)
Alex         Robinson     30         10         20      (empty)
George       Leopold      10         10         10      (empty)
Alex         Robinson     20         20         20      (empty)

Names        Last name    price1     price2    price3   (no named column)  
(no named row)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alex         Robinson     60         50         70      (a string)
Bill         Towns        10         40         50      (empty)
George       Leopold      10         10         10      (empty)
```

But instead of 3 columns imagine I have 100. Thus I cannot do them explicitly by their name for example

EDIT2 : I forgot to tell you that some rows also contain a string. Unfortunately I get an error for this command

```
df8 = data.groupby('Name').sum()
```

I have already sorted the dataframe  with this command

```
data2 = data.sort_values('Name',ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Please post code you have tried

Comment: and sample data, which you could get with `df.head(10).to_dict('split')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `df.groupby`

```
df = df.groupby('Names').sum().reset_index()
```

Output

```
    Names  price1  price2  price3
0    Alex      60      50      70
1    Bill      10      40      50
2  George      10      10      10
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had an error. I updated the question to see the error and kinda the data frame i have

Comment: @Alex  Did it raise `KeyError: 'Name' is not in the columns`? try using `'Names'` as it is the label of your first column

Comment: No it raised 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Comment: @Alex you are doing somethig else before grouping, which is modifying the dataframe and causing that error... honestly it is extremely hard to tell just by the small pieces of info you provide at a time... I would strongly suggest making a big edit of your question (almost rewriting it all), to provide real data including a reproducible example and df.info(), along with all the relevant code you are using and full tracebacks of any exception you might get...

Comment: Here are some tips for debugging on your own as well https://techblog.bozho.net/tips-for-identifying-and-debugging-problems/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will sum your score:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['alan',10],['tom',23],['nick',22],['alan',11]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','score'])
df = df.groupby(['name'], as_index=False)['score'].sum()

print(df)
```

The results:
Before:

```
   name  score
0  alan     10
1   tom     23
2  nick     22
3  alan     11
```

And after:

```
   name  score
0  alan     21
1  nick     22
2   tom     23
```

Comment: Yes somewhat like that. But if i have 100 columns with different names? Thus i cannot use just by name 'score' for example. And some columns have names and some are unnamed.

Comment: Could you post some peace of dataFrame to better understand your issue? @Alex

Comment: Yes i just did! Thank you for your immediate feedback

Comment: I still have a question :D What would you like to have a result in this string column? Array of strings or 'string1string2string3..."?

Comment: Just for the string i wouldn t want to add them. Basically they have the same string lets say 'Cities' I want to remain as 'Cities'  not 'CitiesCities' etc